# How to use from C# a Rust function that has another function as a parameter?

Tags: c#, rust, language-interoperability

The following example illustrates what I am looking to do. The *operation* function receives a value and a function as a parameter, then returns the execution of the function. So far everything is perfect. Now I would like to use that function *operation* in a library to consume in C#.

```rust
fn operation(number: i32, f: &dyn Fn(i32) -> i32) -> i32 {
    f(number)
}
fn square(number: i32) -> i32 {
    number * number
}
fn cube(number: i32) -> i32 {
    number * number * number
}

fn test() {// passing a function as parameter, OK :)
    println!("{}", operation(5, &square));
    println!("{}", operation(7, &square));
    println!("{}", operation(3, &cube));
}

// Tried without success :_(
/*
#[no_mangle] 
pub extern "C" c_operation(number: i32, f: &dyn Fn(i32) -> i32) -> *mut i32 {
    unsafe {
     &mut f(number)
    }
}
*/
```

What should the right signature of the function `c_operation`?

I think that the following C# code should work when the signature is well defined in the library.

```cs
const string RSTLIB = "../../PathOfDLL";

public delegate int Fn(int number);

[DllImport(RSTLIB)] static extern int c_operation(int x, Fn fn);

int Square(int number) => number * number;
int Cube(int number) => number * number * number;

void Test()
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", c_operation(5, Square));
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", c_operation(7, Square));
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", c_operation(3, Cube));
}
```

I appreciate your attention

Comment: You have a problem involving Rust and C#, but how do C and C++ come into the picture? Please don't spam unrelated tags.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Add these Tags because interoperability to C# coming from a Rust, C, or C++ library, is not very different in C# code.

Answer (score 4):

For use from C, one way to declare `c_operation` and define it in terms of `operation` would be something like:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn c_operation(
    number: i32,
    f: unsafe extern "C" fn(i32) -> i32
) -> i32 {
    operation(number, &|n| unsafe { f(n) })
}
```

Comment: Yes! c_operation(5, Square) : 25
c_operation(7, Square) : 49
c_operation(3, Cube)   : 27

Answer (score 3):

`dyn` pointers are not FFI safe, so they cannot be passed through `extern "C"` barriers. You actually get a warning about this:

> warning: `extern` fn uses type `dyn Fn(i32) -> i32`, which is not FFI-safe.

However you can pass a plain function pointer, as long as it is also `extern "C"`, of course):

```
#[no_mangle] 
pub extern "C" fn c_operation(number: i32, f: extern "C" fn(i32) -> i32) -> *mut i32 {
    unsafe {
        &mut f(number)
    }
}
```

(You are returning a dangling pointer to a local temporary, but I guess that is just because you are writing dummy code.)

Then, from C, you can use plain functions, but there is no place for the *closure* data. That would be an issue for C or C++, but not for C#, because it does some magic that creates raw plain function pointers from any delegate, as long as you decorate the delegate type properly:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate int Fn(int number)
```

Then, your `c_operation()` declaration should just work, except that your return type in C# `int` while the Rust version returns a pointer. That corresponds to `IntPtr`:

```
[DllImport(RSTLIB)] static extern IntPtr c_operation(int x, Fn fn);
```

Also, note that if the `c_operation()` stores the pointer `fn` to call it later, then in C# you *must* keep the delegate object alive, either holding it in a variable, or allocating a `GCHandle` to it.

```
    Fn fSquare = Square;
    //keep fSquare somewhere
    c_operation(5, fSquare);
```

If you fail to do that, and the Garbage Collector collects the automatic temporary delgate (that the compiler created for you), and then the Rust code tries to call the stored function pointer... well, it will not be nice.

Comment: consider adding this knowledge to https://github.com/shepmaster/rust-ffi-omnibus

Comment: @Stargateur: I didn't know that page, it is quite nice, but I'm sorry, I'm not very familiar with that Jekyll thing this web is using, or many of the languages involved. But feel free to copy any piece of text from my answers here.

Comment: Hi @rodrigo,

Can you help give some more explanation to “..must keep the delegate object alive..”.
Does that mean you are not able to give a lambda expression like `c_operation(5, (i) => i * i)`?
It is quite hard to test, since I can’t trigger a Garbage Collection while the `c_operation` is running. But I’m surprised if it is true that the runtime isn’t smart enough to avoid the closure being garbage collected.

Comment: @schwartz: You may be right. I had issues with the GC collecting delegates before, but maybe it was for callbacks that were called asynchronously, after the call to the "extern" function had ended. Then I got the habit of always store the delegate in a variable before using it in an "extern", just in case.

Comment: @rodrigo do you mean you started a task within the callback? Could you maybe provide an example?

Comment: @schwartz: I mean that the Rust code stored the callback in a `Box<dyn Fn()>` or similar, and used it later to call the function, asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

[User4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600898/user4815162342)'s answer was exactly what I intended. I would like to add that it is surprising that you can pass a C# function as a parameter to a Rust function, and get a result. Likewise, we can from C# pass a Rust function to the same Rust library in a callback. To round off the matter I am going to show the result.

```rust
//  user4815162342 answer:
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn c_operation(number: i32, f: unsafe extern "C" fn(i32) -> i32) -> i32 {
    operation(number, &|n| unsafe { f(n) })
}

// by example
#[no_mangle]
fn cube(number: i32) -> i32 {
    number * number * number
}
```

The C# code:

```cs
const string RSTLIB = "...\release\rstlib.dll";

public delegate int Fn(int number);

[DllImport(RSTLIB)] static extern int c_operation(int number, Fn fn);
[DllImport(RSTLIB)] static extern int cube(int number);

int Square(int number) => number * number;
int Cube(int number) => number * number * number;

public void Test()
{
    // passing a C# function as parameter of Rust function
    Console.WriteLine("c_operation(5, Square) : {0}", c_operation(5, Square));
    Console.WriteLine("c_operation(3, Cube)   : {0}", c_operation(3, Cube));

    // passing a Rust function as callback inside the same Rust function
    Console.WriteLine("c_operation(5, cube)   : {0}", c_operation(5, cube));

    // Output
    // c_operation(5, Square) : 25
    // c_operation(3, Cube)   : 27
    // c_operation(5, cube)   : 125
}
```

Thanks for your attention.